# Appcmd command not working

Tags: command-line, iis-7.5, appcmd

```
appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name='xxx - yyy'].processModel.idleTimeout:0.00:00:00
```

When I run this command, instead of receiving a validation message or an error message, the  command goes "idle".
It actually just display the caret and I can write text, or wathever... until I CTRL+Break the command.
I tried waiting for 10 minutes but nothing else ever happens.

It's really weird, the command seems correct :S

Do you know what I possibly could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when there is a space in the application pool's name, you have to put the "modification parameters" in quote.
So the command should actually be like this:

```
appcmd set config /section:applicationPools "/[name='xxx - yyy'].processModel.idleTimeout:0.00:00:00"
```

It really gets me to wonder why the simple quotes aren't useful enough.